# Why does songName[i]!= null evaluates to T when it should be F

Tags: java

I need to split the given array and print the string w/o WUB. Below should print "ABC" but instead prints ",,ABC". To be able to print ",,ABC" it needs to satisfy condition songName[i]!= null which should return F for those cases. Still new to Java and programming at all

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String SongDecoder = "";
    String song = "WUBWUBABCWUB";
    String[] songName = song.split("WUB");
    int cnt=0;


    for (int i = 0; i < songName.length; i++){
      if (songName[i]!= null){
        if(cnt == 0){
          SongDecoder = songName[i];
          cnt+=1;
        } else {
        SongDecoder = SongDecoder+","+songName[i];
        }
      }
    }

System.out.println(SongDecoder);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(songName));
  }
}
```

Comment: it just checks that that element of the array is in fact an instance, and not a null. it can only return true or false, false if that element is null, true otherwise

Comment: `split` does not return `null` but empty`""` segments.

Answer (score 2):

`split()` returns empty `String`s when there are no characters between two separators, not null.

Therefore, you should check for empty `String`s in addition to your `null` check:

```
if (songName[i]!= null && !songName[i].isEmpty())
```

Or, actually, in this case, it would be enough to check that the `String` is not empty (since it can't be null):

```
if (!songName[i].isEmpty())
```

Comment: I would argue that given the context you could omit the null-check? Or Yoda-style `! "".equals(songName[i])`